# Using dynamic action to hide/display a LOV based on another LOV with a variable condition

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm using apex 4.2 for this

Here's what i'm trying to do: I have a defined LOV that is the union of a query that gets schema type and a query that gets database type.  Based on the value of that LOV, i want a 2nd drop down to appear only of the value selected in the 1st LOV is a schema

I haven't found anything relevant on google for that.  I know there is also the javascript approach that could probably do what i want but my attempts so far didn't go well but i don't mind going there if someone already did something similar that worked

Let me know if more details are needed, thx

What i have so far: I created a dynamic action that on change of the 1st LOV if the value is in the list of schema, then display the 2nd LOV, if not keep it hidden.

This work very well with the only problem that i need to put the hard coded list in the condition value for it to work properly.  I wanted to put the query result in a variable and use that variable in the dynamic action so that it would work in all cases even if the schema type list change over time.

To recreate my set up, you'll need a LOV item that should be filled with at least 4 elements that you can very well call 1, 2, 3 and 4.  Then create a 2nd item to be displayed based on the value of the LOV.  Create a dynamic action based on change of item LOV with condition in list (1,2) with true action displaying 2nd item

Now what i'm looking for is replace the actual in list (1,2) by :P1_VARIABLE that would contain value "1,2"

Expected results: When page loads, the LOV is hidden, when a schema value is selected, LOV appears

Actual results: Exactly that when using dynamic action with hard coded list of value in condition.  When using a variable instead, LOV never shows up

Javascript attempts always displayed the LOV no matter what was selected

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, using bind didn't work because there is no passed value which make sense but when i tried with string replacement it didn't work either but it's because Apex needs a . at the end of the variable to do the replacement so that's why this option wasn't working either.

So if anyone else has the same issue, just put `&variable.` in your condition field and it should work fine

Comment: I'm not sure the &P1_ITEM. syntax (which is case sensitive) belongs anywhere in the problem described. I would consider a client side condition on a number of dynamic actions that check Item = Value - no punctuation required.

Comment: I wanted a dynamic action with a "in list" condition using a variable as the value, that's where the &P1_ITEM. syntax comes into play because you need string replacement to affect the variable value to the condition value

Comment: So you now have a potential SQL injection / SGA flooding issue (by manually building SQL string)? Maybe check out https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dynamic-in-lists